# How do Mark Sweep and Scavenge counts work?

Tags: tomcat, jmx

I have groovy code that mines tomcat every minute and dumps the results into a DB, as follows:

```
while(true){
def values = []
// some code omitted
//java.lang:type=GarbageCollector PS Scavenge, PS MarkSweep
def markSweep = new GroovyMBean(server,     'java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS MarkSweep') 
values.push(markSweep.CollectionCount)
values.push(markSweep.CollectionTime) //in ms

def scavenge = new GroovyMBean(server, 'java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS Scavenge') 
values.push(scavenge.CollectionCount)
values.push(scavenge.CollectionTime) //in ms
}
```

I then monitored the output over time today and this is what I was seeing:

[GC Monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AP0x.jpg)

You can see the counts and times are monotonically increasing. I was expecting the counts to go up and down based on the number of objects in memory.  Are the times and counts for these MBeans cumulative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they're monotonic counters. If you want to track the rate, store the Delta of a reading and the prior.